# Modify audio output stream of QMediaPlayer

Tags: c++, qt, audio, qtmultimedia, qmediaplayer

I'm trying to port an audio player from Qt4 to Qt5, and from Phonon to QtMultimedia.
Everything works fine with a QMediaPlayer, except that I can't find any way to modify the audio stream between the output of QMediaPlayer and the system sound.
I would like to apply a post-processing effect to the audio.

Any way to do this? Maybe by sub-classing QMediaPlayer? I've checked the QAudioOutput and QAudioDecoder classes but I would have to implement a lot of things to get the same behaviour as QMediaPlayer.

Thanks!

Comment: Which platforms would it need to work on? At least on some platforms qtmm uses pretty high-level APIs, so there won't be a generic solution I'm afraid

Comment: It's for Windows only.